# Callback method is not called when using WinAPI WH_CALLWNDPROC hook

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I want to get messages when a window is moving.

I started to write a simple c++ console application that hooks into the default notepad application of windows.
One part of it contains the following code to set the hook (not all three, only one)

```
_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, CallWndProc, _dllInstance, tid); //WORKS
_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, CallWndProc, _dllInstance, tid); //WORKS
_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, _dllInstance, tid); //DOESNT WORK
```

So basically the procedure of the hooking is the same and every hook type works with the same callback function.
Why does it not work with the WH_CALLWNDPROC?
When applying WH_CALLWNDPROC the hook is successful like the others but it simply doesn't work.

This is the callback function

```
// The callback function
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::cout << "callback " << counter++ << "\n";

    //This is a must
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

But CallWndProc is never called when setting this hook.

I even tried to call the CallWndProc function inside of the DLL but this also didn't work so I removed it entirely from the DLL and now it's an empty DLL. Even if it worked, it would be of no use to me because I need to handle the messages in my application not on the target thread.

Any Tips? Here is the full code

```
#include "Main.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>


/* Variable to store the HANDLE to the hook. Don't declare it anywhere else then globally
or you will get problems since every function uses this variable. */
HHOOK _hook;

// the dll instance
HINSTANCE _dllInstance;

//HOOKPROC _dllCallback;

int counter = 0;

// The callback function
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::cout << "callback " << counter++ << "\n";

    //This is a must
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

// This functions installs a hook to a window with given title
int InstallHook(const wchar_t* title) {

    /* 1. Get window handle of given title */
    std::wcout << "INFO: Getting window handle for \"" << title << "\"...\n";
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, title);
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not find target window.\n";
        return -1;
    }
     
    /* 2. Get ThreadID (TID) of the window handle */ 
    std::wcout << "INFO: Getting TheadID (TID) of \"" << title << "\"...\n";
    DWORD pid = NULL; // If we dont know -> NULL
    DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    if (tid == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not find target window.\n";
        return -2;
    }

    /* 3. Load in the DLL */
    std::wcout << "INFO: Loading the DLL\n";
    _dllInstance = LoadLibrary(TEXT("winhooks_dll.dll"));
    if (_dllInstance == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not load DLL...\n";
        return -3;
    }

    /* 3.5 Get Callback function from dll*/
    //_dllCallback = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(_dllInstance, "_wmProcCallback@12");
    //if (_dllCallback == NULL) {
    //  std::cout << "ERROR: Could not get Callback function from dll instance\n";
    //  return -4;
    //}

    /* 4. Install the hook and set the handle */
    std::wcout << "INFO: Setting the hook...\n";
    _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, CallWndProc, _dllInstance, tid); // The local callback version
    //_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _dllCallback, _dllInstance, tid); // The dll callback function
    if (_dllInstance == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not set hook handle\n";
        return -5;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {

    const wchar_t* title = L"Untitled - Notepad";

    if (InstallHook(title) != 0) {
        std::wcout << "ERROR: Could not install hook on " << title << " last error -> " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    std::wcout << "SUCCESS: Hook is successfully installed on " << title << "\n";
    std::wcout << "Running message loop..." << std::endl;

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: The WH_CALLWNDPROC hook procedure must reside in the DLL being injected. A WH_CALLWNDPROC hook runs in the message loop of the target thread, not in your app thread. You will have to use IPC to send the message info back to your main app.

Comment: Is the app in question a 32bit or 64bit process? Is the DLL 32bit or 64bit? Hooking another process requires the DLL be injected into that process. You can't inject a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process, and vice versa.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Everything is 32bit and I am aware of that. Ok, so I need to inject the dll and initialize the hook from inside the dll right? But the dll injecting is done by the SetWindowsHookEx in my app - so do I need to use it in the dll too? The concept to achieve my goal is quite unclear for me... Is IPC really needed for such a thing? Just for getting the window move event...?

Comment: yes, the actual injection is handled by SetWindowHookEx(), which requires the HINSTANCE of the DLL, and a pointer to the hook procedure in the DLL. If the hook procedure runs in another process, as is the case for a message hook for a thread in another process, the hook procedure can't reside in your main app. It doesn't matter whether you install the hook from inside the DLL or inside your main app, since SetWindowsHookEx() will be called in the context of your main app either way

Comment: And what about the HOOKPROC function? SetWindowsHookEx works with the HINSTANCE and the HOOKPROC callback function from the dll as a function pointer.
Does this mean I need to call SetWindowsHookEx twice to achieve it? Anyway, I am gonna try out a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: as I already said earlier, when hooking another process, the HOOKPROC function must be in the DLL, and a pointer to it given to SetWindowsHookEx(). No, you do not need to call SetWindowsHookEx() twice, unless you are hooking 32bit and 64bit processes at the same time, thus needing 32bit and 64bit DLLs. But you said that is not the case.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831540/not-getting-window-procedure-messages-after-hooking-wh-callwndproc) is an explanation and spy++ also captures no message on untitled notepad.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo I see... I also used winspector to analyze messages and none of my windows gets one. Does it mean that I need to create the hook and a message loop inside the dll afterward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, source platform (32bit or 64bit) must be matched to destination platform.(In my 64bit machine, notepad is 64bit.)
Secondly,for a hook procedure in DLL, Don’t verify whether it works or not by print, the same as std::out. The DLL has nowhere to print its content. The following code uses a file stream.

```
// The callback function
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        if (wParam > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "sent by the current thread wParam=" << wParam;
        }
        CWPSTRUCT* s = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;

        //have no
        std::cout << " Index=" << nwinhooksdll++ << " s->message=" << s->message << " s->hwnd=" << s->hwnd << " s->wParam=" << s->wParam << " s->lParam=" << s->lParam << "\n";
        //MessageBox(NULL,L"CallWndProc",L"CALLBACK",0);

        //works
        myfile << " Index=" << nwinhooksdll++ << " s->message=" << s->message << " s->hwnd=" << s->hwnd << " s->wParam=" << s->wParam << " s->lParam=" << s->lParam << "\n";
    }

    //This is a must
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

[image]