# how to capture wm_activate message in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi

I want to install a hook in python using win32api module and capture the wm_activate message, so that I can do further processing on it, and then release the message to other applications to process. basically I want to detect whether user has changed the active foreground window. I have used QTimer from PySide2 module to check every 25ms whether active foreground window has changed or not, but it's not the best solution.

here's my attempt, but I get no messages out of it, as the low_level_handler callback function is never executed. It worked for low level mouse hook. What am I missing?

```
# Some of this adapted from BoppreH's answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817531/applying-low-level-keyboard-hooks-with-python-and-setwindowshookexa
import win32con, win32gui
from ctypes import wintypes
from ctypes import windll, CFUNCTYPE, POINTER, c_int, c_void_p, byref, WINFUNCTYPE 
import atexit

Handlers=[]

def listener(yo):
    def low_level_handler(nCode, wParam, lParam):
        print("reach")
        print(nCode,wParam, lParam)
        #Be nice, return next hook
        return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    
    # Our low level handler signature.
    CMPFUNC = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_void_p))
    # Convert the Python handler into C pointer.
    pointer = CMPFUNC(low_level_handler)

    windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
    windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR]
    windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA.argtypes = (c_int, wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.HMODULE, wintypes.DWORD)
    print(yo)
    hwnd = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(None)
    hook_id = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(win32con.WH_CALLWNDPROC, pointer, hwnd, 0)
    HOOK_ID = hook_id


    # Register to remove the hook when the interpreter exits.
    atexit.register(windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, hook_id)
    while True:
        windll.user32.PostThreadMessageW(hook_id, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, 0, 0)
        msg = win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        win32gui.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
        win32gui.DispatchMessage(byref(msg))

WM_QUIT = 0x0012
HOOK_ID = None

def installHook():
    listener("yo")

def removeHook():
    windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(HOOK_ID)
    HOOK_ID = None

installHook()
```

Comment: Unlike a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook, a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook needs to be injected into the target process. This requires that the hook procedure is compiled into a DLL, and that DLL's bitness matches the target application's bitness.

Comment: As IInspectable said, the WH_CALLWNDPROC hook procedure must reside in the DLL being injected. You can refer to this thread: [Callback method is not called when using WinAPI WH_CALLWNDPROC hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458380/callback-method-is-not-called-when-using-winapi-wh-callwndproc-hook)